# No result in database when POST ID element in Javascript into PDO Insertion

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have this following code to handle selection in select form:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pilStock').change(function() {
    var pilih_stock = $("#pilStock option:selected").text();
    var hargaZ =  $("#hargaX").text();
        $.post("countme.php",{ hrg: hargaZ, dstock: pilih_stock},
            function(data) {
                document.getElementById("hasilhitung_pilihstock").innerHTML=data;
                document.getElementById("jmlqty").innerHTML=pilih_stock;
            }
        );
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Then I need to declare PHP variable, as:

```
$stock=isset($_POST['pilStock']);
$stock=strip_tags($stock);
```

After that, I need to save the data in $stock in the database but it gave me nothing.
This is the INSERT code I used:

```
$data = $xvg->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (prod_stock) VALUES (:prod_stock)
$data->execute(array(':stock'=>$stock));
```

---

I tried it many times and makes me dizzy... please.

## UPDATED:

Here's the SELECT OPTION which is related to $pilStock:
`$stockz` variable is from `SELECT * FROM other_table` (then the result must be selected by user and saved it in the database)

```
<?php
$stockz=$row['stock'];
if ($stockz=='1'){
    echo "<select name='select' class='form-control' id='pilStock'>";
    echo "<option value='1'>1</option>";
    echo "</select>";
    }
elseif ($stockz=='2'){
    echo "<select name='select' class='form-control' id='pilStock'>";
    echo "<option value='1'>1</option>";
    echo "<option value='2'>2</option>";
    echo "</select>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: you're sending a variable called dstock from js to php. But in PHP you're reading pilStock. I recommend you to use a print_r($_POST); to know what variable are your receiving in php

Comment: Its been awhile since I did much PHP, but when you set `$stock=isset($_POST['pilStock']);`, wouldn't that just set the variable to `true` or `false` based on whether or not the data is even set, rather than actually storing the value?

Comment: how to use 'print_r($_POST)' in my code @BredeBS.

Comment: Perhaps you're right @Jordan Foreman but how can I call 'pilStock' to save the value in my database. pilStock is inside of SELECT OPTION as:
'<select name='select' class='form-control' id='pilStock'>'

Comment: You access the value of a submitted form element by its name. If name="select", then to access the selected value in the posted to .php file, you'd say $pilStock = $_POST['select'].

Comment: @JordanForeman, I use $pilStock=$_POST['select']; in my code. It didn't work. But when I checked it again, the code is inside <form></form>. Well, I got mistakes.

Then, I place below the javascript and it works! How happy I am .. you know, I tried this all day :D .. thks so much!

Comment: @HermanNz you can use that when you start the php script, also use the firebug or another tool for get html console in your browser.  If you try that you will see that you're receiving two values: hrg & dstock.

Comment: @BredeBS yeah I also need to call both and to see the process (I use firebug console). you're right .. no errors in 'other php file' I called. it said 200 OK. Then it really occurred in $pilStock. I've done with it by calling "name" of SELECT and everything's fine.
Thanks. I get two nice solution today ^_^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT Script:

```
<?php
if ($stockz=='2'){
    echo "<select name='select' class='form-control' id='pilStock'>";
    echo "<option value='1'>1</option>";
    echo "<option value='2'>2</option>";
    echo "</select>";
    }
?>
```

Previous:

```
$pilStock=$_POST['pilStock'];
```

Note: That didnot work because Javascript is being used by other PHP file in the same dir.

After:

```
$pilStock=$_POST['select'];
```

Note: This works when the **name** of the SELECT OPTION is called.
@JordanForeman.

--- please donot vote down if you feel this answer is crazy. just let me know how I should be. :p